# add amount to existing amount not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add an amount to an existing item amount in my inventory.

It's not adding up though, what am I doing wrong?

```
  def add_item_to_inventory (theItem, theAmount)
    @playerinventory = Playerinventory.find(params[:id])
    @item = Item.find(theItem)

    if !@item.nil?
      if !@playerinventory.item_for_inventories.find_by_item_id(theItem)
        @ifi = ItemForInventory.create(:item => @item, :amount => theAmount)
        @playerinventory.item_for_inventories << @ifi

      else
        oldAmount = @playerinventory.item_for_inventories.find_by_item_id(theItem).amount
        newAmount = oldAmount.to_i + theAmount.to_i

        @playerinventory.item_for_inventories.find_by_item_id(theItem).amount = newAmount
      end

      if @playerinventory.save 
        return true
      else
        return false
      end

    end

    false
  end
```

The `if` part works like a charm. The `else` does not

Note, `theItem` is an item_id. And obviously after I do `@playerinventory.save`

Comment: save with bang save! and see what's wrong , I think some validations may be failing.

Comment: Saving with a new ItemForInventory works like a charm, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

item_for_inventories seems to be a relation with playerInventory , you are saving playerInventory after updating ItemForInventory , you should save ItemForInventory or may be update it ..Like `@playerinventory.item_for_inventories.find_by_item_id(theItem).update_attributes(amount: newAmount)`

Comment: @CaptainCarl would you mind accepting my answer , if it helped you.